react JS with Masonic infinite load - loading content before render causes div width to remain 0
I'm currently having an issue with the masonic api where I wait to render the page until I have the initial content loaded.
I have an example here. The page will load after the load screen but you have to change the screen dimensions to get the masonry grid to pop up.
Basically I just have a simple div that gets replaced when the loading state has changed.
Seems that the trouble is that the ref I'm using remains 0 until I render the thing, which makes sense.
In this case is there a way to force-re-render the masonry component after loading?
The one thing I tried that sort of worked was putting in an alternate width (the document's width) as a placeholder.
